# Permission of the webpage folder /var/www on a Linux server

Tags: linux

I have moved my website from Godaddy to a VPS server. I'm new to Linux so I followed some tutorials online but still confused about some problems.

I use SSH to log on my server as user adam. In order to run the PHP properly, I have to set 755 permission to `/var/www` and change the owner of this folder to www-data. But that means I don't have permission to write files in this folder even if add user adam to the group www-data. And I cannot upload webpages onto this folder using FTP which is very annoying. (Currently I have to type su to switch to root and then modify these files with nano)

I know setting 777 is a solution but it may cause some safety concerns so I'm looking for a better solution.

> drwxr-xr-x  8 www-data www-data 4096 Jul 24 21:36 www

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every number of permisson is composed as follows

4: read
2: write
1: execute

So if you add them you get the permission. By example 7 means all the permisons and 6 means read and write.

The first number of 755 is for the owner, the second for the group's users and the third for other users.

Then 755 means rwxr-xr-x it is the owner can read wirte and execute, but the group member can't write.

If you want to solve this you can change the privileges to 775 then it will be change to rwxrwr-x

Comment: Really helpful. The third number is for other users so should I change  it to 0 to enhance the security?

Answer (score 0):

Or you can add www-data as a secondary group to adam and set a setgroupid www-data fro /var/www